# Trying to test performance of 2 JSON frameworks - does it look correct?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, gson

In my app - I'm using JSON for serializations and up to this point - I was using GSON. Ok, it was kind of slowish especially initial sign in where I load objects.

I explored options and found Jackson. I did quick test with looping and deserializing 1000 of sample objects. Jackson was like 3x-5x faster.

Now, I built wrapper to I can switch between libraries and started to test while looking side by side at what I'm getting from each library. Here is my code:

```
public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws Exception
    {
        T returnObject;

        Long milliseconds = (new Date()).getTime();
        returnObject = MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson().fromJson(json, classOfT);
        Long gsonTime = (new Date()).getTime() - milliseconds;

        milliseconds = (new Date()).getTime();
        returnObject = MyJacksonWrapper.getMyJson().readValue(json, classOfT);
        Long jacksonTime = (new Date()).getTime() - milliseconds;

if (gsonTime < jacksonTime)
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "------------- GSON Wins by " + Long.toString(jacksonTime - gsonTime) + " object: " + classOfT.getName());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "------------- Jackson Wins by " + Long.toString(gsonTime - jacksonTime) + " object: " + classOfT.getName());
        }
```

Is there flow in my code on how I get time measurments? 
Bottom line is - different is negligible and GSON proved to be working so I don't know.. Real life was different from my initial evaluation. And it doesn't *feel* faster with jackson either..

```
02-17 10:23:26.068: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- GSON Wins by 108 object: [Lcom.idatt.json.UserPreference;
02-17 10:23:28.006: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- Jackson Wins by 34 object: [Lcom.idatt.json.MailTemplate;
02-17 10:23:29.154: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- GSON Wins by 27 object: [Lcom.idatt.json.MailItem;
02-17 10:23:36.514: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- Jackson Wins by 599 object: [Lcom.idatt.json.TripUser;
02-17 10:23:50.260: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- Jackson Wins by 1 object: [Lcom.idatt.json.TripUpdate;
02-17 10:24:00.455: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- GSON Wins by 45 object: java.lang.Integer
02-17 10:24:00.541: DEBUG/com.idatt.json.JsonWrapper(12004): ------------- GSON Wins by 34 object: [Lcom.idatt.json.Device;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To try and normalize out the differences due to VM Dynamic behavior as well as a warm/cold JVM, try timing each loop running 10,000 times then see what the differences are.

Also note that the first set of code run will have a different time from the second set just due to VM randomness; so flip flop those and then average the times.

Net-net, I doubt you will find any significant difference.

Aside: if milliseconds make a big difference, look at the stream parses that both Jackson and GSON provide for faster raw acess (but you will be in charge of parsing logic and rebuilding your objects which may be a net loss)

Comment: If I may add, if milliseconds make a difference, look at a different serialization protocol.

Comment: Very good answer, the only thing I would add is to test the numbers on actual devices and not only in the emulator, as there are in some cases extreme differences.

Comment: Actually, it was my stupid... All slowness came from writing data to database (SQLite), not from serializing. After making proper trace logs - I figured that JSON parsing wasn't an issue at all to begin with...

Comment: Katit, glad you found the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The usual caveats here (google for tips on doing Java performance measurements if these are new):

- You MUST run enough measurements to stabilize timing results -- JVM takes a while to optimize code (compile from bytecode to native). This means at least 10 seconds or so before taking any measurements
- Do not pass Strings, unless your input must come as Strings -- overhead of reading input, converting to String is generally unnecessary, and fastest way is to pass in `InputStream` or `byte[]' (or, for parsers that accept neither,`Reader`built from`InputStream`
- (minor) Don't construct `Date`s; just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or 'timeNanos`) for getting timings.

My guess is that you may have forgotten first part, and thereby results are somewhat arbitrary and change from run to run.